Only getting 100mbps LAN when docks are daisy-chained but gigabit when connected directly
My M1 Max Mac is connected to a Microsoft Audio dock that is then connected to a Lenovo Thinkpad dock which then has ethernet. This setup works with my Windows laptop, but doesn't on my Mac. When I connect the Lenovo dock directly, it works as expected but (the horror!) that means connecting two cables to dock.
What would cause this? While it would be nice to overcome the issue, just knowing the root cause would be great as well!
USB tree when daisy-chained:


I checked the Lenovo site which details the 5 Lenovo docks available (at least in the UK) and there is no indication they are compatible with macOS. The Microsoft dock does state clearly that it is compatible. Why not try docks specifically designed with macOS in mind, such as those available from OWC?

Mainly because "compatible" doesn't necessarily mean it will work as daisy-chained. The Lenovo dock works as expected when directly connected, just not when connected after the Microsoft hub. I'm guessing there's some negotiation that happens that determines there's not enough headroom to connect at gigabit ethernet.

Have you tried setting the speed of the affected Ethernet port manually to 1 Gbps in System Settings? Maybe autonegotiation is failing to give you the maximum speed.
